# Trying to include FB insights in my website, still getting invalid app_id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am just following http://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/ and i add the meta tag to the  in index.php but i am getting  the error:

The app ID "xxxx81342935368" specified within the "fb:app_id" meta tag was invalid.

I do see FB insights for my FB page, but i like to add FB insight to my regular website

How can i fix this?

regards

Answer (score -1):

ok almost fixed.
I had to create a seperate application and i had to be logged in under my personal account and not as one of my FB pages.

Now adding the app_id of one of my FB pages as fb:admins doesn't work, is this possible at all??

Comment: "Almost fixed" isn't an answer, nor should an answer contain a question.